# Trying to fresh install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on new computer without OS but can't install r8125 2.5G Realtek Ethernet driver

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ethernet

I, a total noob, have a similar issue to:
[2.5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125 installation guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263363/2-5g-ethernet-linux-driver-r8125-installation-guide)

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Desktop on new no-OS Desktop but have no internet/bluetooth (tried USB wifi dongle and tethering to my iphone but both methods were too complicated for me).
Live USB is using r8169 but I am trying to activate r8125 for ethernet access so can use auto update/3rd party update option during install.

However, despite attempting DKMS pkg and regular Realtek driver manual activation, using a USB and steps outlined in the above link and elsewhere (eg, tried blacklist, rmmod, disabling Secure Boot, etc.), I still can't run autorun.sh
It states sudo: ./autorun.sh: command not found

It also says dkms command not found when I try:
sudo cp -R /path.to/source/ /usr/src/r8125-9.003.05

My kernel version is 5.4.0-42-generic.

Both r8169 and nouveau have a chip error, which I understand to mean that the included opensource drivers are inadequate for both my Realtek Ethernet & my Nividia graphics.

I did extract both the r8125-9.005.01.tar.bz2 and r8125-dkms-master.zip files before I tried both methods of autorun
Each dir has different files the tar one has autorun.sh, Makefile, README, & an src dir; the zip one has .gitignore, autorun.sh, dkms.conf, Makefile, README, README.md, & an src dir
I ran ./autorun.sh both in their respective dir as well as every step up from src dir past home as well as put in the paths to ensure that that was not the reason for the failure.

I don't understand most of what you said @user535733 but I am in that chicken and egg situation.
I already tried to tether and dongle but both methods seemed just as or more complicated than disabling r8169 and activating r8125 module.
Thanks again for your help and advice.

Yes, @guiverc.
I downloaded manually on USB the Realtek driver and also the dkms pkg to create a module.
However, as I stated, I am uncertain why neither autorun are working.
Perhaps what you are referring to is different than either?
If it would not be too much trouble, would you mind directing me to the exact pkg I need to download and walk over with my USB?
I am also not sure I can use the pkg as it looks like I also need to migrate "make" pkg with its dependencies as well.
I followed the instructions of both the blacklist r8169/autorun r8125 as well as tried the dkms method but both failed at the autorun step.
Perhaps it is impossible to run these when I do it on a "try Ubuntu" Live USB???
I have still not been able to figure out this problem.

Comment: Which Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?  20.04? 20.04.1? 20.04.2?  and Desktop? or Server? of which...   The point release detail lets us know the kernel & software stack you're starting with, currently unknown, but we need desktop or server as well  (they have different defaults; Server uses GA kernel by default, Desktop defaults to HWE kernel)

Comment: You should provide more specific details as to what is in the directory when you run `./autorun.sh` as what you've provided so far looks like a user error (ie. you failed to expand the archive, or weren't in the correct directory where you expanded it, as the "./" would need amending if you aren't in the correct location..)  FYI:  The "./" has the same meaning as in windows; it's just needed in windows because $PATH includes "." in windows, where as it does not in a pure POSIX environment.

Comment: The packages needed to compile are not included in a stock install of Ubuntu. For some folks, this creates a chicken-and-egg problem: They need network access to compile the drivers to get network access. If possible use an alternative method of network access to install the `build-essential` package (and all of the dependencies), then your driver will likely build. You can use wired networking, or mobile networking, or borrow a friend's wireless USB dongle.

Comment: If you can't access internet via dongle etc, you can always download packages on another box & walk across via thumb-drive.   There are loads of options on the page https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline (some involve software to aid you, you don't need any of that, `wget` (download) & `dpkg` (install) being basics (`apt` can be used instead of dpkg but don't forget you're offline, so need to provide packages it would normally download from the web).